# Need a linq join that also compares properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of entities.  Imagine list1 is remote and list2 is local - list1 was created some time in the past and list2 has just been generated.

I want to compare both lists, matching by .id, and comparing the .flag property only of each element.  Where the .flag property is different, I want to select the older element, but with the .flag property from list2 (The new list).

The example below shows how to select just the entities in list1 that are different.  How can I select the entities from list1 that are different, but using the .flag property from the list2 entity.

Note: I don't want to `select new SomeEntity(){}` an entire SomeEntity class as in the real problem, the classes I'm working with have a lot of properties.

```
class SomeEntity
{
    public int id;
    public bool flag;
    public int some_value = -1;
}

// Setup the test
List<SomeEntity> list1 = new List<SomeEntity>();
List<SomeEntity> list2 = new List<SomeEntity>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    list1.Add(new SomeEntity() { id = i, flag = true, some_value = i * 100 });
    list2.Add(new SomeEntity() { id = i, flag = true, });
}
// Toggle some flags
list1[3].flag = false;
list2[7].flag = false;

// Now find the entities that have changed and need updating
var items_to_update = from x in list1
                      join y in list2 on x.id equals y.id
                      where x.flag != y.flag
                      select x;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your code, after retrieving the `items_to_update` collection:

```
 foreach (var item in items_to_update)
 {
     item.flag = list2.Where(c => c.id == item.id).SingleOrDefault().flag;
 }
```

Comment: This is what I'll do - many thanks.  I guess all this boils down to what Ziav said, linq is not the tool for modifying entities.  I'll thin it down to `item.flag = list2.Single(c => c.id == item.id).flag;`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I select the entities from list1 that are different, but using the .flag property from the list2 entity.

and

> I don't want to select new SomeEntity(){}

Means that you want to modify entity in list1 before return. Linq is not clear tool for do that.

```
foreach (var item in  from x in list1
                      join y in list2 on x.id equals y.id
                      where x.flag != y.flag
                      select new {x, y})
{
    item.x.flag = item.y.flag
    yield return item.x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ziav - you're absolutely correct when you say linq is the wrong tool for modifying values.